# Issue using Shapefiles generated with QGIS in CadnaA

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I frequently use the shapefiles from QGIS and ArcMap in other no GIS software, predominantly a noise software [CadnaA](http://www.datakustik.com/en/products/cadnaa).

CadnaA has the ability to import shapefiles, look for matching attribute names and associated the corresponding attributes to the CadnaA object type. Attributes such as 'Name', 'ID', 'LW_LI' etc... can be picked up and automatically inserted into the softwares object.

ArcMap does this perfectly. QGIS does not.

I am assuming that there is some sort of difference in the shapefile, but cannot determine what. I have seen elsewhere that it might be something to do with the shapefile type (3D perhaps?).

Edit:

Sorry this took so long. Here are examples of the shapefiles. The Arcmap ones import perfectly but the QGIS ones do not.

[ArcMap Shapefiles](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EvW78dNsribDIM0-27Wu-Lmuta6HX4X5)

[QGIS Shapefile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C9sg6OcV9V9qagPTHAZre9d8QGPpLf71)

Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Put a small shapefile a) that works with CadnaA and b) that does not work with it available somewhere.

Comment: Agreed @user30184, without interrogating the data that does and doesn't work we're just stabbing in the dark on software we don't necessarily have or have had exposure to. Also please indicate the fields that are required by the software. Note: dbf files associated with shapefiles can be opened in Excel to view but **don't save them in Excel!!!**

Comment: Added links to example shapefiles!

Comment: @user30184 files added

Comment: @Michael Stimson files added

Comment: The spatial index appears to be bad. You can recreate one with OGRInfo https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-January/031532.html thus: **ogrinfo -sql "CREATE SPATIAL INDEX ON Sources" D:\path\to\Sources.shp** then it should be identical to the Esri created one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the problem.... Though a crappy answer. The shapefile cannot be loaded in QGIS during the import. For some reason if it is loaded in QGIS, CadnaA cannot pull the labels from the attributes table.

Hopefully this will be helpful for others importing into non GIS software.

Comment: Perhaps CadnaA wants to open the attribute file (.dbf) in edit mode and fails  because QGIS has locked it.